# characters simplified Chinese or Traditional

Tags: meaning, traditional-vs-simplified

### 唰唰
寥寥
are these characters of simplified Chinese or Traditional ?
I am studying simplified Chinese, hence not quite sure whether I need to know them.
Moreover, there is no relevant translations for them.

Your answers would be appreciated much.
Thank you in advance:)
George

Comment: They are simplified AND traditional.

Comment: 唰唰 寥寥 is a sound effect

Answer (score 2):

None of the existing answers are wrong, but I do not think any of them properly explain it fully, so I will add an explanation of what simplified chinese actually is and how it related to various standards for clarity.

---

Start with a super basic synopsis of the past before standardization:  Many different forms of characters existed, either coming and going over the years, or side by side as equal alternatives-- sometimes it was as simple as a font difference when deciding how a character was written.

When standardization happened, each region that uses chinese characters chose what they want to be the official normal one in use-- even places like japan or korea did so.

Simplification is a process that happened side by side with standardization in some places and not others-- examples of two places that did simplify would be mainland china and japan.  Simplification itself is the process of simplifying SOME characters in use-- that some is pivotal for properly understanding the situation, because even in "simplified" chinese, many many many characters are not simplified whatsoever.

Lets give some examples to help showcase this. In mainland china, the standardized character for traditional 愛  is a simplified 爱.  In japan, the standardized character is not simplified, but it is 愛 just like traditional.  In both places traditional 龍 was simplified-- but in china it was simplified to 龙 while 竜 was chosen as standard in japan.  And in both places 獻 was simplified to the same 献. In both places 悲 remains the same as traditional and unsimplified.

So now we have addressed that simplification only effects some characters and not all, and the fact that simplification does not automatically have the same standards in all places.  Next lets address the fact that many unsimplified characters vary place to place as well, due to different forms being chosen as standard for the region.  A perfect example exists in my chinese name, the character 強 in traditional.  The mainland standard is 强, an entire stroke longer! This is clearly not a simplification, and is just two alternate "spellings" side by side, like color and colour.

So, please know that many chinese characters are exactly the same in multiple regions, and that "simplified" and "traditional" just refers to whether any simplification was done at all during standardization.  Also note that most (not all) simplification is based on cursive chinese, so its possible to still see them in handwriting or other use even in traditional areas.  The line is not that sharp of a divide.

Its not set in stone, but generally less common characters are very unlikely to have been simplified, unless it is a mass simplification-- 言 side component simplifying to the cursive form 讠in all characters in mainland as an example.

---

This ended up being very long, but I hope that when I say 唰唰 寥寥 is the exact same in simplified and traditional chinese, the reasoning why thats the case makes sense. As for needing to know these words, I think its nothing to focus on learning-- not because you are learning mandarin by mainland china standard, but because they are very rare vocab and not super useful ((唰唰 is a swishing sound effect 寥寥is an uncommon way to say "very few"))

Hope this helps o(∩_∩)o

Answer (score 1):

Both characters can be found in 【康熙字典】and earlier dictionaries. They cannot be simplified Chinese.

【康熙字典】

唰：《玉篇》《集韻》所劣切，音刷。《玉篇》鳥治毛衣也。又《集韻》數滑切。小嘗也。

寥：【廣韻】落蕭切【集韻】力交切【韻會】【正韻】憐蕭切，音聊。【說文】空虛也。【玉篇】寂也，廓也。【莊子·大宗師】吾聞之冥，冥聞之參寥。【註】莊子僞立此名。【楚辭·九辯】寂寥兮收潦而水淸。

又【遠遊】下崢嶸而無地兮，上寥廓而無天。

又【廣韻】郞擊切【集韻】【韻會】郞狄切，音歷。義同。　【集韻】本作廫。

Answer (score 0):

They're in simplified Chinese.

"**唰唰**" has no meaning but "sound like" word,

e.g.

树叶在风中**唰唰**作响。

The tree leaves were rustling in the wind.

吉普车开始向前行驶,汽车雨刮在挡风玻璃上**唰唰**地来回摆动.

The jeep started forward and the wipers began to sing across the screen.

---

寥寥 means "few", it always used like 寥寥无几:

e.g.

意识到危险的人**寥寥无几**。

Too few are awake to the dangers.

自愿参加，但响应者**寥寥无几**。

A call for volunteers was sent out, but very few people responded.

Answer (score -1):

They're in simplified Chinese.：)